# Different behavior when accessing a base class when it's a template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

When I write `A::B::C`, with `A` being a class, and `B` being its base class, I assume I'm accessing `C` which is defined in that base `B`. This wouldn't work when `B` isn't actually a base of `A`. However, the same apparently isn't true when `B` is a template, e.g. `A::B<123>::C` still gives me `B<123>::C`, and it doesn't seem to matter whether `B<123>` is actually a base of `A` or not. I'm at a loss why there could be a difference. Does it not interpret `A::B<123>` as accessing base class `B<123>` of class `A`? Why not? Can it be rewritten somehow so it does interpret it like accessing a base class?

Here's a snippet explaining what's done in detail, with comments explaining every step:

```
// Here we show that we can't access a non-existent base of A
namespace WorksAsExpectedWithoutTemplates {

struct B
{
  using C = void;
};

struct D
{
  using C = void;
};

struct A: B
{
};

// Compiles as expected, B is a base of A, so Foo is B::C, aka void
using Foo = A::B::C;

// Doesn't compile, as expected, because D isn't a base of A, even though D::C
// exists
using Bar = A::D::C; // WE DON'T EXPECT THIS TO COMPILE, WHICH IS FINE
}

// Now we try the same thing with templates, and it doesn't behave the same way.
// Why?
namespace ActsDifferentlyWithTemplates {

template< int >
struct B
{
  using C = void;
};

struct A: B< 42 >
{
};

// Compiles as expected, B< 42 > is a base of A, so Foo is B< 42 >::C, aka void
using Foo = A::B< 42 >::C;

// Compiles, Bar is B< 123 >::C, even though B< 123 > is not a base of A. Why
// does this behave differently than in the non-template case above? Can this be
// rewritten differently so that this wouldn't compile, same as in
// WorksAsExpectedWithoutTemplates, since B< 123 > isn't a base of A?
using Bar = A::B< 123 >::C; // WHY DOES THIS COMPILE? B< 123 > isn't a base of A
}
```

Comment: `A::B<123>::C` is interpreted as `A::template B<123>::C`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`template< int > struct B` has an [injected-class-name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name#In_class_template) `B` that acts as a template name if it immediately precedes a `<`. The class `struct A` inherits this.

So, `A::B< 123 >::C` is the same as `B< 123 >::C`, not the base class `B< 42 >`. For example:

```cpp
template<int X>
struct B {
    using C = char[X];
};

struct A : B<42> {};

using Foo = A::B<42>::C;
using Bar = A::B<123>::C;
using Baz = A::B::C;  // (injected-class-name without template)

static_assert(sizeof(Foo) == 42);
static_assert(sizeof(Bar) == 123);  // This is a different type
static_assert(sizeof(Baz) == 42);
```

None of these cases actually are "accessing a base class". They are all inheriting the injected-class-name from the base class like any other member type alias / member template.